# How to convert english font to telugu font in desktop application using swings

Tags: java, swing, fonts

Recently I have developed a desktop application "hotel management system" using Swing and that's working great!

But now the newest requirement is that the application should be in *telugu* font! That means the GUI of the application should be in *telugu* and the bills and the reports and everything in the application should be in *telugu*...

So my question is, is this possible? If so, then what technology should be used along with swings to make that happen?
If anything new should be applied along with the Swing then I'm keen to learn it and use it in my application!

Please help me out. I don't know how this can be done.

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. If the new font is a variable width, it will effect your layouts, so be careful. The Swing part is relatively easy, depending on the look and feel you're using. Your reports are a different matter. What look and feel are you using? How are your reports generated?

Comment: @MadProgrammer the reports are generated using **jasper**. and the look and feel i am using is for windows xp  **SystemLookAndFeel**

Comment: I'm not at my pic at the moment, but I can tell you are going to have some problems with Jasper, it's very possible, but you will need to supply all the variations of the font in Jar file that Jasper needs to be able to access

Comment: yes but i still i dint got a complete idea about how to handle that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the default font isn't particularly difficult, so long as you are prepared.

Take a look at [Custom Fonts for Jasper Reports](http://javaskeleton.blogspot.com.au/2010/12/embedding-fonts-into-pdf-generated-by.html) on how to bundle your fonts with Jasper Reports.  It would also be advisable to check with the offical docs and forums for more up-to-date info.

There are plenty of examples on the web, simply do a Google for *"Jasper Reports custom fonts"*

Setting the required font for Swing isn't difficult, but a lot will come down to how the look and feel you use stores it's properties.

Now depending on whether the font is installed on the system or if you are supplying the font as an embedded resource, you may or may not need to do the following.

If you're not relying on the font been installed on the system, but are providing it yourself, then you need to load it.

```
// Load the font, for example "Telugu.ttf"
String fName = "/fonts/" + name;
InputStream is = null;
try {
    InputStream is = DemoFonts.class.getResourceAsStream(fName);
    font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
} finally {
    try {
        is.close();
    } catch (Exception exp) {
    }
}
```

Otherwise you should be able to simply create `Font` object using the requied `Telugu` font family name.

Next you want to change the default fonts used by the current look and feel to that which you want to use.  This must be AFTER you install the look and feel and BEFORE you create ANY UI elements.

```
Object[] keys = keySet.toArray(new Object[keySet.size()]);

for (Object key : keys) {

    if (key != null && key.toString().toLowerCase().contains("font")) {

        Object oValue = UIManager.getDefaults().get(key);

        if (oValue != null) {

            String value = oValue == null ? null : UIManager.getDefaults().get(key).toString();
            UIManager.put(key, font);

        }

    }

}
```

Now, you need to be aware that Swing tends to use fixed width fonts by default in it's look and feels, changing the font to a variable width font WILL change your layouts.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible without using fonts. Use Telugu Unicode to display telugu language and even for JASPER reports. I developed English to Telugu Transliterator using telugu unicode without using any font system. Just configure all label names in telugu, kannada, hindi and load with transliterator.